# How can I cause an UPDATE query to throw an error?

Tags: database, postgresql

In my database I have the following table

```
       Table "public.session"
  Column   |     Type      | Modifiers
-----------+---------------+-----------
 sessionid | character(10) | not null (primary key)
 device    | character(5)  |
 userid    | character(5)  | (foreign key, can be null)
```

What I want to do is occasionally update a row in this table to change the userid from NULL to a value. However, if userid ISNT null I want to throw an error so I can catch it in my backend server. Currently, my query looks like:

```
update session set userid = $1 where sessionID = $2 and userid = NULL;
```

The problem is that this query doesnt fail when userid is NULL. How can I cause it to fail?

Comment: Can you just look at the number of rows updated? If it is 0 then throw the error in code.

Comment: It can be definitely done in a trigger... Though, it may be not the most efficient or easy way to achieve it.

Comment: @VladimirBaranov yes it seems you're right. Im very new to Postgres and hadnt heard of triggers. Thank you

Comment: Not clear. Maybe: `update session set userid = $1 where sessionID = $2 and userid = NULL AND $1 IS NOT NULL;`  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following @Mark Watson's comment, I simply checked the number of rows updated. This isn't exactly what I wanted but its certainly easier than writing a trigger.